# Sequencing Product listing

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have more than 20 products of same category 
how do I store its position and use to show user side(user will see admin set sequence order)

Like form admin if I set

```
p_10 
p_11
p_5
p_6
```

from

```
p_5
p_6
p_10
p_11
```

can use array

```
$sequence=array(p_10,p_11,p_5,p_6);
```

store it in database table column or is there any other method of doing same thing

Comment: I am not sure I understood - you want to sort them? keep the original order? 
can you please try to elaborate or give simple input-output example?

Comment: just add a sorting order to the data set.

Comment: I get the array of sequence order after the drag and drop with jQuery ui library @dWinder    like this data[p_10,p_11,p_5,p_6]

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to extract number from your string value and then sort array based on this number.

```js
const arr = ['p_10', 'p_11', 'p_5', 'p_6'];

arr.sort((a,b) => {
 let num1 = extractNumber(a);
 let num2 = extractNumber(b);
 
 return num1 > num2 ? 1 : num2 > num1 ? -1 : 0;
});

function extractNumber(stringValue) {
 return +stringValue.substring(stringValue.indexOf('_')+1);
}

console.log(arr);
```